# uploading arabic files in django not working returning codes

Tags: django, nlp, arabic

i have a view in my django project that should be able to read the content of an uploaded .txt file from the input type="file", but the thing is that with arabic content it doesn't print the actual text, but a series of codes "\xd9\x88\xd9\x82\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84" and i couldn't find any solution for this since the file is perfectly viewable on my pc and my website it the one exporting that file in "utf-8". any help here ?

```
Uploaded_File = request.FILES["Doc"]
for chunk in Uploaded_File.chunks(chunk_size=None):
    print(chunk)
```

Comment: If `chunk` is a `bytes` object the you should be able to use `chunk.decode()` to convert it to a readable string

Comment: It worked! thank you dude you just saved me!